# Do you like Music? This word is Historic

Tags: word

A nine letter word

> Starts with a person ends with the same person
>
> Starts with a place ends with a place
>
> Exactly in the middle, a very common name

Can you guess?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer could be:

> METRONOME - a device for keeping time when playing a musical instrument.

*Starts with a person ends with the same person*

> It starts and ends with ME.

*Starts with a place ends with a place*

> It starts with either the MET (i.e. the Metropolitan museum of Art in New York) or the METRO (the Paris underground system) and ends with NOME (in Alaska)

*Exactly in the middle, a very common name*

> The middle 3 letters are RON, a common name.

As for being 'Historic':

> From Wikipedia: *A kind of metronome was among the inventions of Andalusian polymath Abbas ibn Firnas (810–887). In 1815, Johann Maelzel patented it as a tool for musicians, under the title "Instrument/Machine for the Improvement of all Musical Performance, called Metronome".*